# EF Two-to-Many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Section object that is in relationship with exactly two Node objects. Basically, the Section object is a route with a starting point and an ending point. I can't find a lot about Multiple-to-Many relationships and I don't even know if this is a thing.

```
public class Section
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public Node StartNode { get; set; }
    public Guid StartNodeId { get; set; }
    public Node EndNode { get; set; }
    public Guid EndNodeId { get; set; }
}


public class Node
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}
```

This should not work :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
            .HasOne(se => se.StartNode)
            .WithMany(sn => en.Sections)
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.StartNodeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
            .HasOne(se => se.EndNode)
            .WithMany(en => en.Sections)
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.EndNodeId);
```

Should I map this as a Many-to-Many relationship ? I would like to have access to the Sections from a Node, and the two points from my Section.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually wanting is multiple `one-to-many` with the same entity.

So your `Node` class should be as follows:

```
public class Node
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Section> StarNodeSections { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Section> EndNodeSections { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the *Fluent API* configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
            .HasOne(se => se.StartNode)
            .WithMany(sn => sn.StarNodeSections) // <--  Here it is
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.StartNodeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
            .HasOne(se => se.EndNode)
            .WithMany(en => en.EndNodeSections) // <--  Here it is
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.EndNodeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```